# sqlx::query! Macro with uuid::Uuid Fails to Compile in Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I'm attempting to insert data into a `PostgreSQL` database using `sqlx::query!` macro in Rust. However, I'm encountering a compilation error related to the `uuid::Uuid` type not satisfying the Encode trait.

**Error Message:**

> the trait bound `uuid::Uuid: Encode<'_, Postgres>` is not satisfied

**Code Snippet:**

```
use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse};
use sqlx::PgPool;
use uuid::Uuid;
use chrono::Utc;

pub async fn subscribe(form: web::Form<FormData>, connection: web::Data<PgPool>) -> HttpResponse {
    sqlx::query!(
        r#"
        INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, email, name, subscribed_at)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
        "#,
        Uuid::new_v4(),
        form.email,
        form.name,
        Utc::now()
    )
    .execute(connection.get_ref())
    .await;
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

**Cargo.toml Dependencies:**

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.4.0"
sqlx = { version = "0.7", default-features = false, features = ["runtime-tokio-rustls", "macros", "postgres", "uuid", "chrono"] }
uuid = { version = "0.8.1", features = ["v4", "serde"] }
chrono = "0.4.15"
```

**Attempts to Solve:**

- I have ensured that the uuid feature is enabled in sqlx.
- I tried different versions of uuid to check for compatibility.
- I ran cargo clean and cargo build after changes to Cargo.toml.

**What could be causing this trait bound issue and how can I resolve it? Is there a version mismatch, or am I missing a necessary feature activation?**

**Update**

I update the codes with this codes but still show me error :

```
use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse};
use chrono::Utc;
use sqlx::types::Uuid;
use sqlx::PgPool;

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct FormData {
    email: String,
    name: String,
}

pub async fn subscribe(form: web::Form<FormData>, connection: web::Data<PgPool>) -> HttpResponse {
    let my_uuid = Uuid::parse_str("a1a2a3a4b1b2c1c2d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8")?;
    
    sqlx::query!(
        r#"
    INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, email, name, subscribed_at)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
    "#,
        my_uuid,
        form.email,
        form.name,
        Utc::now()
    )
    // We use `get_ref` to get an immutable reference to the `PgConnection`
    // wrapped by `web::Data`.
    .execute(connection.get_ref())
    .await;
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

it shows me this error :

```
let my_uuid = Uuid::parse_str("a1a2a3a4b1b2c1c2d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8")?;
```

> the `?` operator can only be used in an async function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
> the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, sqlx::types::uuid::Error>>` is not implemented for `HttpResponse`

Comment: You should use the [`Uuid` from `sqlx`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/types/struct.Uuid.html), not from the `uuid` crate.

Comment: @Jmb sqlix [reexports](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/6ecb5831f49bbc5b1b693c1b223a2a3b7e346b69/sqlx-core/src/types/mod.rs#L34) `Uuid` from the `uuid` crate, so if versions match, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I Update the Question

Comment: @Jmb I Update the Question

Comment: Not sure what's unclear about your function having to return `Result` or `Option` but returning `HttpResponse` instead which is neither of the former two options, can you expand on that? You simply can't use `?` here (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlx doesn't know how to serialize a `Uuid` but it knows how to serialize a `String`, so you can convert the `Uuid` to `String` using the `to_string` method on `Uuid`:

```rust
pub async fn subscribe(form: web::Form<FormData>, connection: web::Data<PgPool>) -> HttpResponse {
    sqlx::query!(
        r#"
    INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, email, name, subscribed_at)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
    "#,
        // Here we use the `to_string` method on `Uuid`
        Uuid::new_v4().to_string(),
        form.email,
        form.name,
        Utc::now()
    )
    .execute(connection.get_ref())
    .await;

    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

In the updated version of your code, you are parsing a `String` into an `Uuid` which may fail, that's why the `Uuid::parse` method returns a `Result`, you can either unwrap it (if you are sure that it's a valid Uuid) or handle the error like so:

```rust
pub async fn subscribe(form: web::Form<FormData>, connection: web::Data<PgPool>) -> HttpResponse {
    // unwrap it
    let my_uuid = Uuid::parse_str("a1a2a3a4b1b2c1c2d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8").unwrap();

    // or, handle the error
    let my_uuid = match Uuid::parse_str("a1a2a3a4b1b2c1c2d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8") {
        Ok(uuid) => uuid,
        Err(err) => {
            return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body("Invalid uuid");
        }
    };
    
    sqlx::query!(
        r#"
    INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, email, name, subscribed_at)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
    "#,
        // We have to convert `Uuid` to `String`
        my_uuid.to_string(),
        form.email,
        form.name,
        Utc::now()
    )
    .execute(connection.get_ref())
    .await;
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

Comment: as many people pointed out you can use the Uuid type in the sqlx crate, and remove the `to_string` method used in the above examples

Comment: thanks for your answer . i removed the `.to_string()`  and it solve

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to run the same code from Zero to Production by Luca Palmieri.  It turns sqlx 0.5.x has a [bug](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/discussions/1845):

> Uuid breaks with version 1 with SQLx

upgrading it from .5.X to the latest 0.7 in Cargo.toml fixed the problem in the original.